# Problem in unable to validate spinner must be click

Tags: android

Adapter.class

```
holder.txt_AddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String product_image = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductImgPath();
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.edtxt_integer_number.getText().toString());


    }
});
```

Here, When I am click this button must be asked to select `spinner`

Is there any way to validate spinner or put "select something" in the first position of a spinner which is filled by `objArraylist`

```
ProductSpinnerAdapter productSpinnerAdapter = new ProductSpinnerAdapter(context, brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList());
holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(productSpinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: In custom layout there are a spinner as well a button..
spinner data is there from a arraylist.

Now I want without spinner click i can't click this txt_AddToCart

Comment: Do you want to get the currently selected item?

Comment: i am getting exact data if i select spinner but if not selecting spinner then getting wrong data

holder.spinner_product_details.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Subproductname = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList().get(i).getName();
            }

Comment: So the problem is only initally? is that what you are specifying?

Comment: See I have updated my question

Comment: Check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String product_image = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(holder.spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getProductImgPath();
```

change **holder.spinner** to respective spinner variable.

Let me know if this works